# Although no errors in code, a Simple Calculation purpose app crashes

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I have a simple Android app to perform some calculations.
Although there are no errors in the files and the build runs successfully, the app crashes.

I'm using Android Studio 3.1, and testing this app on android API 23.

My code:
(see update)

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate_flight_time"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="71dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="Calculate Flight Time"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:onClick="calculateFT"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.54"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/droneType"
        android:layout_width="245dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="319dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="This app intends to help drone pilots compute/predict their UAV's flight time beforehand, providing a better insight into prospective builds"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.578"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="By Shlok Jhawar"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/batteryCapacity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="Battery Capacity (mAh)"
        android:text="3000"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/droneType" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MAPM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="43dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="20"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Max amps per motor"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/batteryCapacity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/MTPM"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Max thrust per motor (g)"
        android:text="900"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MAPM" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/droneWeight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Weight of drone"
        android:text="1800"
        android:inputType="number"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/MTPM" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I'm not sure why this is happening.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
One step ahead, my code does not crash. (Thanks Manishoaham and Faysal).
Made some other tweaks as well. **But now, time_in_seconds evaluates to infinity**, and I can't figure out. Please help.
Here's my new code:

```
package com.example.android.uavuptimecalculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
//import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int number_of_rotors;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner typeOfDrone = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.droneType);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        typeOfDrone.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        typeOfDrone.setSelection(1);

        String drone_type = typeOfDrone.getSelectedItem().toString();
        if (drone_type=="Tricopter") {
            number_of_rotors=3;
        }
        if (drone_type=="Quadcopter") {
            number_of_rotors=4;
        }
        if (drone_type=="Hexacopter") {
            number_of_rotors=6;
        }
        if (drone_type=="Octacopter") {
            number_of_rotors=8;
        }
        EditText Battery_Capacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.batteryCapacity);
        String stringA  = Battery_Capacity.getText().toString();
        EditText Amps_perMotor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MAPM);
        String stringB = Amps_perMotor.getText().toString();
        EditText Thrust_perMotor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MTPM);
        String stringC = Thrust_perMotor.getText().toString();
        EditText Weight_ofDrone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.droneWeight);
        String stringD = Weight_ofDrone.getText().toString();
        int battery_capacity_mah =Integer.parseInt(stringA!=null&&!stringA.isEmpty()?stringA:"0");
        //int battery_capacity_mah = Integer.parseInt(Battery_Capacity.toString());
        //int total_max_ampdraw = Integer.parseInt(Amps_perMotor.toString()) * number_of_rotors;
        int total_max_ampdraw = Integer.parseInt(stringB!=null&&!stringB.isEmpty()?stringB:"0") * number_of_rotors;
        //int total_thrust = Integer.parseInt(Thrust_perMotor.toString()) * number_of_rotors;
        int total_thrust =  Integer.parseInt(stringC!=null&&!stringC.isEmpty()?stringC:"0") * number_of_rotors;
        //float required_throttle = Integer.parseInt(Weight_ofDrone.toString()) / total_thrust;
        float required_throttle = Integer.parseInt(stringD!=null&&!stringD.isEmpty()?stringD:"0") * number_of_rotors;
        /*if (required_throttle>=1){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UAV will not take off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }*/
        float avg_ampdraw=required_throttle*total_max_ampdraw;

        String abc = Float.toString(avg_ampdraw);
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,avg_ampdraw,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        float battery_capacity_ah=battery_capacity_mah/1000;
        float time_in_hours=battery_capacity_ah/avg_ampdraw;
        final float time_in_minutes=time_in_hours*60;
        final float time_in_seconds=time_in_minutes*60;
        //public void calculateFT()
        Button CalculateFTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_flight_time);
        CalculateFTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                mBuilder.setTitle("Calculated Flight Time");
                //mBuilder.setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);
                mBuilder.setMessage("Your UAV will fly for "+time_in_seconds+" seconds, which is equivalent to "+time_in_minutes+" minutes");
                mBuilder.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            }
        });



    }


}
```

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: Would you please add the XML and Crash log in your question?

Comment: you  are probably trying to parse an empty string at ```Integer.parseInt(Battery_Capacity.toString());```

Comment: @Boukharist how do I fix that then?

Comment: just to be sure , post your error log

Comment: You are dividing `battery_capacity_ah` by `avg_ampdraw`. As per you are getting `time_in_seconds` infinite, here only might be the divide by zero error. `avg_ampdraw` depends on `required_throttle` and `total_max_ampdraw`. If any of these two variables become zero, you will ultimately get `time_in_seconds` infinite. In order to resolve your error in case no text is entered in respective textviews you will have to set default values by `Integer.parseInt(string!=null&&!string.isEmpty()?string:"default_value")` for these two variables only that is in turn used to divide some other values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get text from your editText first:

```
String string = Battery_Capacity.getText().toString();
```

Second, as you already have defined inputStyle as number, you will only get parseable number strings only, but also put a check that you don't get an empty string as below

```
int battery_capacity_ham = Integer.parseInt(string!=null&&!string.isEmpty()?string:"0");
```

Same for all other editTexts also.

**Try use this code:**

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int number_of_rotors;

    //Views as member variables so that kept in memory until activity destroys.
    EditText Battery_Capacity,Amps_perMotor,Thrust_perMotor,Weight_ofDrone;
    Spinner typeOfDrone;
    Button CalculateFTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Battery_Capacity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.batteryCapacity);
        Amps_perMotor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MAPM);
        Thrust_perMotor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.MTPM);
        Weight_ofDrone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.droneWeight);
        typeOfDrone = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.droneType);

        ArrayAdapter<String> myAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.types));
        myAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        typeOfDrone.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        typeOfDrone.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                String drone_type = typeOfDrone.getSelectedItem().toString();

                switch (drone_type){
                    case "Tricopter":
                        number_of_rotors = 3;
                        break;
                    case "Quadcopter":
                        number_of_rotors = 4;
                        break;
                    case "Hexacopter":
                        number_of_rotors = 6;
                        break;
                    case "Octacopter":
                        number_of_rotors = 8;
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });

//        typeOfDrone.setSelection(1);

        //public void calculateFT()
        CalculateFTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate_flight_time);

        CalculateFTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Values from editTexts should be collected at the time of button click event.
                String stringA  = Battery_Capacity.getText().toString();
                String stringB = Amps_perMotor.getText().toString();
                String stringC = Thrust_perMotor.getText().toString();
                String stringD = Weight_ofDrone.getText().toString();

// Removed null checks on strings as EditText never returns null as per android docs
//but empty checks are necessary to avoid app crash in case of parsing exception of empty string
                int battery_capacity_mah =(Integer.parseInt(!stringA.isEmpty()?stringA:"0")) * (80/100);
                int total_thrust =  Integer.parseInt(!stringC.isEmpty()?stringC:"0") * number_of_rotors;//no usage found, so did not confirm it
                int total_max_ampdraw = Integer.parseInt(stringB.isEmpty()||stringB.equals("0")?"1":stringB) * number_of_rotors;//Simplified
                float kgthrust = total_thrust/1000;
                float required_throttle = (Float.parseFloat(stringD.isEmpty()||stringD.equals("0")?"1":stringD)/1000) / kgthrust;
                float avg_ampdraw=required_throttle*total_max_ampdraw;

                String abc = Float.toString(avg_ampdraw);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,abc,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                float battery_capacity_ah=battery_capacity_mah/1000;
                float time_in_hours=battery_capacity_ah/avg_ampdraw;
                float time_in_minutes=time_in_hours*60;
                float time_in_seconds=time_in_minutes*60;
                int tis = (int)Math.round(time_in_seconds);

                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                        .setTitle("Calculated Flight Time")
                        .setMessage("Your UAV will fly for "+tis+" seconds, which is equivalent to "+time_in_minutes+" minutes.")
                        .setNeutralButton("OK",null)
                        .show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You are dividing `battery_capacity_ah` by `avg_ampdraw`. As per you are getting `time_in_seconds` infinite, here only might be the divide by zero error. `avg_ampdraw` depends on `required_throttle` and `total_max_ampdraw`. If any of these two variables become zero, you will ultimately get `time_in_seconds` infinite. In order to resolve your error in case no text is entered in respective textviews you will have to set default values by `Integer.parseInt(string!=null&&!string.isEmpty()?string:"default_value")` for these two variables only that is in turn used to divide some other values.

Comment: The error happens even when a value is entered. Could there be any other possible error? However, I added these lines:-        if (stringB==null) {
            stringB="20"
        }

Comment: Ok, I haven't seen before. As I see, you are getting strings from all editTexts in your onCreate method and while created, editTexts are always empty. And you are not getting any string on your button click when actually you should collect strings from all of your respective editTexts. You should collect all your strings from editTexts on your button click. EditTexts are kept as member variables, assigned in onCreate and their strings are collected on some events as per good practices.

Comment: Done that too, still same result. Are you sure (string!=null&&!string.isEmpty()?string:"0") works? It appears StringA is always evaluating to 0.

Comment: Please check edits of your activity code for your requirements as per my understanding. Also, as I didn't have resources (layout files of views), you will have to resolve any compilation errors in case occur.

Comment: Thanks for the new code.Certainly much better than the previous one but now I find a lot of weird stuff.

Comment: In the line float required_throttle = Integer.parseInt(stringD.isEmpty()||stringD.equals("0")?"1":stringD) * number_of_rotors;, * number_of_rotors should have been replaced with / total thrust. But now, even after fixing that, (float required_throttle = Integer.parseInt(stringD.isEmpty()||stringD.equals("0")?"1":stringD) / total_thrust;), Weight_ofDrone and total thrust not zero, but still reqd throttle evaluates to zero. Why? everythings looks fine. Check my WORKING python code if needed :) https://github.com/shlokj/OpenDFT/blob/master/Flight%20Time/Flight%20Time%20and%20Destination.py

Comment: I just used ternary operator for compacting code style.https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Comment: In my code, `stringD.isEmpty()||stringD.equals("0")?"1":stringD`, simply checks whether `stringD` is `""` or `0` (condition as first parameter). If this condition is true, it returns second paramenter (`"1"` in our case) else (i.e. if condition fails), it will return `stringD`. If it's not fitting well in your app's logic you can manipulate it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Getting text from EditText have some problem. For getting the text from EditText use this line:

```
String string = yourEditText.getText().toString();
```

You need to add `getText()` before `toString()` for getting the text.

```
int battery_capacity_mah = Integer.parseInt(Battery_Capacity.getText().toString());
int total_max_ampdraw = Integer.parseInt(Amps_perMotor.getText().toString()) * number_of_rotors;
int total_thrust = Integer.parseInt(Thrust_perMotor.getText().toString()) * number_of_rotors;
float required_throttle = Integer.parseInt(Weight_ofDrone.getText().toString()) / total_thrust;
```

Hope this will help.